# Entity Framework Populating Child Objects using Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I hope this isn't a duplicate as I have been looking but I was looking more at the reasoning behind this.

I have set up a user object.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {

    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("StatusID")]
    public Status Status { get; set; }
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("RoleID")]
    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
}
```

And the Child Objects

```
public class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    [Key]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

When I call

```
var testuser = dbContext.User.Where(u => u.CompanyID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

I get users.Status as being null, but users.StatusID = 1.

however, if I call

```
var status = dbContext.Status.ToList();
var role = dbContext.UserRole.ToList();
var testuser = dbContext.User.Where(u => u.CompanyID == 1).FirstOrDefault();
```

then call testuser.Status, I can see the correct object related to StatusId of 1.

Can someone explain why this would solve the issue and also how I can make it work without having to call the following beforehand.

```
var status = dbContext.Status.ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: See [Loading Related Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx). Basically here you need eager loading, e.g. `var testuser = dbContext.User.Include(u => u.Status)....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your property like this. Keyword `virtual` put its property to lazy loading and then you can access the whole object.

```
public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
```

And BTW, I edited your class. There are un-needed things, because you can access `StatusID` by property `Status` (like `int statID = Status.StatusID;`) and same to UserRole.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
   {

   }

   [Key]
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int UserID { get; set; }
   public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int CompanyID { get; set; }
   public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
   public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the lazy loading does the job I need it too but I was wondering what the pros and cons were for eager loading/lazy loading and why I would choose one over the other?

Comment: Here lays answer to your question. I hope it helps! http://stackoverflow.com/a/31366407/5592255

Answer (score 5):

You can try as shown below.

**Note :** Use **[Eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager)** with `Include()`

> Eager loading is the process whereby a query for one type of entity
>   also loads related entities as part of the query

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var testuser = dbContext.User.Where(u => u.CompanyID == 1)
                              .Include(p => p.Status)        
                              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I have gone for the lazy loading although both answers are correct, thank you for the help.

Comment: sure no problem :)