# @Html.DropDownList only returns 1 value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn MVC ASP.Net, a step in the tutorial advises writing the following code to return all items in the specified list to a dropdown allowing the user to select the required item.

**Basic Explanation**
Drop down list only shows the current item returned e.g. if the URL is details/2
only 'Pizza' is returned in the list rather than all items in the 'MenuGroups' list.
**Basic Explanation**

Although the code below does work to an extent it does not work the way I am shown in the video, I have even gone as far as going to the website and copying his exact code but I still receive different results and I cannot work out why.

http://cop4834.pbworks.com/w/page/106053825/Menu%20Case%20Study%20Part%204%20-%20Generating%20a%20Javascript%20call%20from%20a%20Razor%20Object

As you can see (If you have time to watch the video the demonstration is at 3:49) all menu groups are returned, my code displays only whatever is passed in via the URL?

```
    <dt>
     Select a Menu Group
    </dt>

    <dd>
       @Html.DropDownList("MenuGroup", new SelectList(Model.MenuGroups,
          "MenuGroupId", "MenuGroupTitle"),
          new { onchange = "selectMenuGroup()" })
    </dd>
```

'MenuGroups' is a virtual list created from the Model 'Menu'

```
    public virtual List<MenuGroup> MenuGroups { get; set; }
```

The controller is as below:

```
    public ActionResult FullDetails(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Menu menu = db.Menus.Find(id);
        if (menu == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(menu);
    }
```

Apologies if this is too long or missed any information, I have looked in to this for many hours before posting but I can only find people saying to use @Html.DropDownListFor instead but I already have a list and so would like to use the above method (and also find out my mistake).

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: If you dropdownlist only contains 1 item, then `Model.MenuGroups` contains only one item - we don't know what `db.Menus.Find(id)` returns - you need to debug your code

Comment: Make sure that the record you are retrieving from the `db.Menu.Find(id);` contains more than 1 item for the `MenuGroups` property. To appreciate the drop-down list.

Comment: As you both suggested the 'List' is actually only being passed 1 item (Although the generated SQL Query returns 3 which confuses me more!) so I will look in that direction instead, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that `MenuGroups` contains multiple items for your selected record.

Then what you can do is replace

```
public ActionResult FullDetails(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Menu menu = db.Menus.Find(id);
    if (menu == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(menu);
}
```

with

```
public ActionResult FullDetails(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Menu menu = db.Menus.Include(r => r.MenuGroups).FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == id);
    if (menu == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(menu);
}
```

Since `MenuGroups` is a navigation property, you can eager load it by specifying `Include(r => r.MenuGroups)`. AFAIK `Find` only returns the entity not including the navigation properties and it is not usable together with `Include`. The reason why EF uses the `virtual` keyword is to allow lazy loading on the property. See [Lazy Loading vs Eager Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31366407/6138713) for more info.

Comment: OP is claiming it does contain one element so the `MenuGroups` property must have been populated

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately that didn't work either so I will continue to look in to it tomorrow.