# Foreign related entity not being populated

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I am attemptiong to fetch some entities from my DB which map to their respective EF Core models, but I am experiencing some difficulties with foreign tables:

Models/accountingContext.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class accountingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TransactionClass>? TransactionClasses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TransactionType>? TransactionTypes { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Models/TransactionClass.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class TransactionClass
    {
        public int TransactionClassId { get; set; } = 0;

        [ForeignKey("TransactionTypeId")]
        public int TransactionTypeId { get; set; };
        public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Models/TransactionType.cs

```
namespace WebApi.Models
{
    public class TransactionType
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int TransactionTypeId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("TransactionType")]
        public ICollection<TransactionClass> TransactionClasses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The intention in the models above is to have the TransactionType table related to the TransactionClass table.  In the DB itself I have also created a foreign key relationship linking TransactionClass.TransactionTypeId or TransactionType.TransactionTypeId.

When I then fetch all classes in the app as follows, the related TransactionClass.TransactionType property is always null instead of the related entity:

```
using (accountingContext db = new())
{
    return db.TransactionClasses.ToList();
}
```

I must be missing something above but I cannot see what it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lazy Loading vs Eager Loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366236/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading)

Comment: @Felix reading the post you referenced I get the impresssion I should use Eager loading for my situation.  However my problem is that I cannot get the related entity in my result set at all

Comment: First, you have to read up on Lazy vs. Eager loading. There are millions of articles on the topic. Second, they way you invoke `ToList()`, it *won't* load related classes unless you explicitly call `Include()`. Another (I consider better) way is to create a DTO that explicitly defines the shape of result object

Comment: @Felix I was missing the call to Include() ... new to EF so assumed it would be automatically populated.  Thanks