# In Entity Framework, with getAll, how can I include a list of my other datasets in same response

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I want to create a response that includes all its model class properties.

While getting all my offers from the database, I am getting `Bundles` and `OffersAddons` returned as null. How can I get get all `Offers` and their `Bundles` and `OfferAddons` in the same response?

```
namespace CarWash.Models
{
    public class Offer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Bundle> Bundles { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OfferAddon> OfferAddons { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bundle
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Package Package { get; set; }
        public int PackageId { get; set; }
        public int OfferId { get; set; }     
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }

    public class OfferAddon
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Addon Addon { get; set; }     
        public int OfferId { get; set; }
        public int AddonId { get; set; }
        public int Qty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

With my function I am getting this error

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')'

This is my `offerCreate` function

```
[HttpPost("create")]
public IActionResult CreateOffer([FromBody] OfferRequestDto offer) 
{
    if (offer == null || !ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var existingOffer = _offerRepository.GetOfferByName(offer.Name);

    if (existingOffer != null) 
    {
        return StatusCode(409, "Offer already exists");
    }

    var offerMap = _mapper.Map<Offer>(offer);

    foreach(var item in offerMap.Bundles)
    {
        var package = _packageRepository.GetPackageById(item.PackageId);

        if (package == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Package id {item.PackageId} not found");
        }

        item.Package = package;
        item.PackageId = package.Id;
    }

    foreach(var item in offerMap.OfferAddons)
    {
        var addon = _addonRepository.GetById(item.AddonId);

        if (addon == null)
        {
            return NotFound($"Add on with id {item.AddonId} is not found");
        }

        item.Addon = addon;
        item.AddonId = addon.Id;
    }

    if (!_offerRepository.CreateOffer(offerMap))
    {
        return StatusCode(500, "Something went wrong while saving");
    }

    return Ok("Offer created");
}
```

Can someone guide me - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're talking about `getAll`, but then you're showing the code for the **create** operation.... that isn't very helpful. You need to **show us** the actual code for `getAll`  so we can see what you're doing there - in order to help how to get the related entities as well ....

Comment: GetAllOffers is a function in my controller that just call my OfferRepository function to get all offers.      [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<ICollection<Offer>> GetAllOffers() 
        {
            var offers =  _offerRepository.GetAllOffers();
            var offerResponseDto = _mapper.Map<List<OfferRequestDto>>(offers);
            return Ok( offerResponseDto );
           
        }  Secondly i showed my create function because i thought, may be i am doing wrong while creating the Offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using navigation properties in Entity Framework, you want to use the virtual keyword.  This will enable lazy loading and the collections will automatically be fetched for you.

```
    public virtual ICollection<Bundle> Bundles { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OfferAddon> OfferAddons { get; set;}
```

If you do not use the virtual keyword, eager loading takes effect.  In this case, you will need to use include in your query.

```
var offer = context.Offers
        .Include(o => o.Bundles)
        .Include(o => o.OfferAddons)
        .ToList();
```

There are instances where eager loading is a better approach than lazy loading and vice versa.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31366407/11376319